# How to pass the entire request from AWS API Gateway to Spring Controller?

Tags: aws-lambda

My project is to deploy the micro-service to AWS Lambda and i am getting the entire request from AWS API Gateway to Lambda Handler till now , but how can i pass my request to Controller class , such that various annotations like @requestmapping can be used.I had searched on Internet also but didn't found any useful resource . 
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway has routing built in. Rather than trying to bypass the router, I would highly recommend that you integrate with it. You can set individual routes to call separate Lambdas, complete with some basic request validation.

If you definitely want to bypass routing, take a look at proxy resources (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html).

> API Gateway defines a proxy resource as a place holder for a resource to be specified when the request is submitted. A API Gateway proxy resource has the following properties:
>
> - A special path parameter denoted as {proxy+}. This path parameter represents any of the child resources under its parent resource of an API. In other words, /parent/{proxy+} can stand for any resource matching the path patten of /parent/*. The + symbol indicates to API Gateway to intercept all requests on the matched resource. This special path parameter is also known as a greedy path variable. The proxy variable is the greedy path variable name and can be replaced by another string in the same way you treat a regular path parameter name.
> - A special method, named ANY, used to define the same integration set up for all supported methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, and PUT.